# Fancybox with ProgressBar + fadeIn + fadeOut + OnTimer + Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, fancybox, overlay

The following code function is what I'm after

```
OnClick = FancyBox(image),FadeIn,FadeOut,Timer & Download + Time = Redirect
```

My goal is to have a functional `FancyBox` that loads `onclick` set to `fadeIn(time)` > show a "progress bar/.gif image" and `fadeOut(time)` initiates a download then redirect(time) to new page. The timer for the redirect would be an awesome perk but if it's not possible that's okay.

```
<style>
#overlay {
background:#EAE8E8;
  position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20%;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    Font-Size:150%;
}
```

```
<div id="overlay">
<img src="http://de.speedmaxpc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/120px-Gray_circles_rotate.gif" alt="Loading" />
```

Loading...

```
   <script>
   jQuery(window).load(function(){
   $("#overlay").fadeTo(3000,1).fadeOut(3000);
 });
  </script>
```

Do I add the redirect and time code to the functional script above or keep it separate in the header of my page?

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function SetUpRedirect() {
     var destination = "http://website.com";
      setTimeout("window.location='"+destination+"'",1000);
     return true;
      }
     </script>    

  <a class="yip" onclick="SetUpRedirect();" href="#"  rel="">click</a>


<a class="yip" onclick="SetUpRedirect();" href="#"  rel="">click</a>
```

Comment: Is this really a [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/) question?

Comment: Yes it is, Im having a hard time figuring out how to make this code functional.

Comment: Just use callbacks to do any stuff you need - fade something, radirect, or whatever